# c++ Image Processing (cropping image from the cell)

Tags: c++, image

I have to do this:
**Crop the image from the cell (3, 3) and with the length and height 5 and 4 respectively.**

I don't know what is meant by "crop the image from the cell," nor how to do it. I have an image stored in a 2D array with the height an length, looking like this:

```
imageArray[h][l]; //h = 8, l = 10.
```

Here is the image data that I have stored in a .txt file that I load into my 2D array:

```
0   255 255 255 0   0   255 255 255 0
255 0   255 255 0   0   255 255 0   255
255 255 0   255 255 255 255 0   255 255
255 255 255 0   255 255 0   255 255 255
255 255 255 255 0   0   255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 0   0   255 255 255 255
255 255 255 0   255 255 0   255 255 255
0   0   0   255 255 255 255 0   0   0
```

Comment: Why not ask "what does it mean to crop the image from the cell" the person who assigned you this task? Also - `C` or `C++`? Pick one, please.

Comment: Maybe they want you to crop from pixel 3,3 as the upper left corner. We have no way of guessing.

Comment: _cell(3,3,)_ probably means the upper left pixel at that position, length and height should be clear.

Comment: Okay, I was hoping that maybe it was common practice to "crop from the cell" and I just didn't know about it. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: It's not really a commonly used term though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [crop](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition%20of%20cropping) 
>   /kräp/ 
>   verb 
>   gerund or present participle: **cropping** 
>   1. cut (something, especially a person's hair) very short. 
>   "she cropped her long golden hair"

The assignment is asking you to cut the image from a 10x8 to a 5x4 image.

They are also asking you to remove the first 3 rows on the left and the first 3 columns on the top.

By your description we can't tell if you need to then put that image you'll be creating into a new 2 dimensional array or if you will be writing those values out to a file, but we do know that you'll want to be copying those "pixel" values somewhere starting at position [3, 3] and ending at [3+5, 3+4]. And since you know where you'll be starting (3), and exactly how far you'll be going (5 or 4), you'll be using for loops.